# Analogous Mathematical term for extending beyond the elements in a set?

Tags: terminology, multisets, music-theory

This question relates to projecting pitches in the context of music theory.  However, I'm looking for the appropriate mathematical term for this particular concept.

#### Here's the musical context:

Imagine you have a set `setA = [0, 1, 2, 3]` that represent scale degrees in a musical scale.  What we want to to is project that set into different musical scales.  If I were to project this set `setA` into a major scale (`setM = [0, 2, 4, 5, 7, 9, 11]`), I would get `result = [0, 2, 4, 5]`.  If I were to project set `setA` into an octatonic scale (`setO = [0, 2, 3, 5, 6, 8, 9, 11]`) I would get `result = [0, 2, 3, 5]`.

To accomplish this, we need to break it down into two types of sets.  `setA` is an "index set" and `setM`, `setO` are each examples of a "projection set".  Note that in this case, the projection sets that we have used so far ultimately map to the scale degrees of the chromatic scale.

#### Extending projections into octaves:

When have have an index set that includes numbers outside the cardinality of a projection set, we want to project the resultant pitches up or down by octaves.  For example, imagine an index set `setB` such that `setB = [0, 3, 5, 7, 10]` that we want to project into the major scale (`setM`).  Done properly, that result would be `result = [0, 5, 11, 12, 17]`, since, once we go up to values at and beyond index `7` from `setB` the resultant projection is now up an octave, and we `+12` to that projected pitch.

#### Extending projections to non-`+12` "octaves":

In the examples above, we are ultimately projecting our pitches into the chromatic scale.  However, not all projection will `+12` at the octave.  If we want to project the index set `setN = [0, 2, 4, 6, 7]` into a projection set representing scale degrees of a diatonic scale `setD = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]` we will need to add a property to a projection set which will indicate what value will be added or subtracted when extending above or beyond the cardinality, in this case `+7`.

Intuitively, the resultant projection of `setN` onto `setD` would be `[0, 2, 4, 6, 7]` (and not `[0, 2, 4, 6, 12]`).

#### Update our Projection sets to include extensions:

To accommodate this, we need to update our definition of a "projection set" to include this value.  Here are some projection sets with extensions included:

`chromatic_scale_in_chromatic_space = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11 | 12]
diatonic_scale_in_chromatic_space = [0, 2, 4, 5, 7, 9, 11 | 12]
diatonic_scale_in_diatonic_space = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 | 7]
triad_in_diatonic_space = [0, 2, 4 | 7]
major_triad_in_chromatic_space = [0, 4, 7 | 12]`

#### Does mathematics have an analog or proper term for this extension value?

And finally, the question. What is the *name* for the property that `+12` or `+7` represents in our updated projection set?  For lack of a more proper term, I'm using the noun "extension" to describe the property, and the verb "extends" to describe the action, but I'm hoping there is a more proper mathematical description for what I'm trying to describe.